# How to add style or attr to ng-repeat element

Tags: angularjs

All:

One question about ng-repeat:

```
var app = angular.module("vp", []);

app.controller("main", function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ["name1", "name2","name3","name4","name5"];
});

app.directive("filter", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    templateUrl: "asset/chart.html",
    controller: function($scope){
      this.setLayout = function(EL){
        var d3EL = d3.select(EL[0]);
        //here below could be style attr or any DOM operation
        d3EL.selectAll(".sm").style("font-size","30px");
      }
    },
    link:  function(scope, EL, attrs, controller){
      controller.setLayout(EL);
    }
  };

});
```

My html is:

```
<html ng-app="vp">
<!-- here is the head part that I did not write-->

    <body ng-controller="main" class="container">
        <filter></filter>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

My template chart.html:

```
<div id="cnt">
    <div ng-repeat="m in names">
        <div class="sm">{{m}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run the setLayout function, I found those elements have not been generated, I wonder how to handle this if I want to set style to those element inside ng-repeat?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: You've got the wrong idea here, don't use your controller to modify the DOM. That's what the link function is for.

Comment: @Dan-Nolan Thanks for help. Could you tell me how can I modify this? Cos Even I put all operation in Link, the element inside the ng-repeat still not get generated by that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're doing it right already, whats missing is just to add another directive for each ng-repeated item that will be using the `filter` directive controller functions to perform its d3 manipulation. The reason why you're code doesn't work is because the `filter` directive's link function is triggered before the `ng-repeat` directive of your `assets/chart.html` template is evaluated, hence your d3 selection does not catch anything. Furthermore, I the solution below promotes re-usability of the `filter` directive by isolating its scope and accepting the `names` scope variable.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/bgQYtV6lOtvsOjZ5TLs7?p=preview)**

**Javascript**

```
  .directive('filter', function() {

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: { names: '=' },
      templateUrl: 'chart.html',
      controller: function() {
        this.setLayout = function(element) {
          var d3el = d3.select(element[0]);
          d3el.select(".sm").style("font-size","30px");
        };
      }
    }

  })

  .directive('filterItem', function() {
    return {
      require: '^filter',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, filter) {
        filter.setLayout(elem);
      }
    };
  });
```

**HTML**

*index.html*

```
<filter names="names"></filter>
```

*chart.html*

```
<div id="cnt">
    <div ng-repeat="m in names" filter-item>
        <div class="sm">{{m}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend you to read the [**Developer's guide for Directives**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), specifically [**Creating Directives that Communicate**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate). Additionally, read the [**$compile API Reference**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) as well.

Comment: `filterItem` is simply just a directive that requires a parent directive (`filter`), that is attached on each `ng-repeat`ed item in your `chart.html`

Comment: Thanks for help. But could you talk a little more about why use filterItem can make that it happen after the template is evaluated?

Comment: This is because each `ng-repeat`ed item is `**compiled**` with a new scope,  therefore any directive added within the `ng-repeat` gets evaluated for each item.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want to accomplish here, but you'll want to do your DOM manipulations (or d3 visualizations) in your link function instead of trying to call them in the controller. When that gets difficult to maintain you should pull them out into a separate JavaScript file and inject them.

Your filter directive could look like this:

```
app.directive("filter", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        templateUrl: "chart.html",
        link:  function(scope, EL, attrs){
            d3.select(EL[0])
              .selectAll(".sm")
              .style("font-size","30px");
        }
    };
});
```

Here's a [plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ocX8VkUebHk3g6LgNn9y?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for help. But what I want to do is to operate those elements generated by ng-repeat rather than set the style on their parent element. Let us consider controller.setLayout(EL); as more complicated DOM operation(like add more elements or attach event handler) on each element generated from ng-repeat. The crucial problem here is how can I get access to those repeat elements? Or How can I know when those element have been generated?

Comment: Ah, I see so I've added your `selectAll()` back in and updated the example. A good way to use d3 with Angular is to `scope.$watch` your angular variables and then tell d3 to render on changes. Then you'd build the D3 component to render based on those variables and it will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Here's an example of watching the names array on your scope and then using d3 when it changes: http://plnkr.co/edit/HdqsIOsmuBdyfpjCMu0H?p=preview

Comment: thanks for help. I do not know why it works on your side. I think I did the similar thing as you, but I can not get any element selection with that selectAll(".sm"). BTW, I can not open that link,. Could you fixed that? Thanks