# How to bind scope data to directive style

Tags: angularjs

All:

Right now, what i want to do is using AngularJS two-way data-binding to change directive style like background color.

```
var app = angular.module("vp", []);

app.controller("main", function($scope) {
      $scope.style={
        "background-color": "red"
      };
    });

app.directive("bg", function($compile){

  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    controller: function($scope){
    },
    compile: function(tEL, attrs){
      return {
        post: function(scope, EL, attrs, controller){
          var d3EL = d3.select(EL[0]);
          d3EL.attr("ng-style", function(){
            return "style";
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }

});
```

The directive is like:

```
<bg style="display:block; width:100px; height:100px;">This is BG directive.</bg>
```

But when I add a div inside this directive, then use $compile, ng-style worked.

```
app.directive("bg", function($compile){

  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    controller: function($scope){
    },
    compile: function(tEL, attrs){
      return {
        post: function(scope, EL, attrs, controller){
          var d3EL = d3.select(EL[0]);
          d3EL.append("div")
              .style({
                width:"50px",
                height: "50px",
                border: "black 1px solid"
              })
              .attr("ng-style", function(){
                return "style";
              })
              .each(function(){
                $compile($(this))(scope);
              });
        }
      }
    }
  }

});
```

I wonder why the ng-style does not work with the directive itself?

Thanks.

Comment: `.attr("ng-style", "style")` works ?

Comment: @PSL that way only work if I compile the div I added later to directive. But for directive itself, this does not work. ToT

Comment: @PSL -- It probably does when the `each` loop runs and calls `$compile`

Comment: @tymeJV yes, I guess the style binding only interpret when $compile applied, but we can not compile directive itself, cos it will lead to a infinite recursive compile, right?

Comment: You need to compile the element container removing the directive attribute from the element (If used as an attribute directive). @tyme yeah i forgot jquery syntax.. :D

Comment: Im still a bit lost on the example - I don't see where you actually give any styles to `ng-style`?

Comment: @tymeJV OP is doing it in the controller.. :) Directive does not seem to create any scope just takes what is available..

Comment: @PSL - This is why naming is important!!! Haha, I see it now :\

Comment: @Kuan Probably try to have a directive template with just a container element and append stuff onto that and then compile that container.

Comment: @PSL Yes, template is also one option. 2 reasons that I do not use it: [1] what I need may very dynamic most time, rather than a fixed structue, I may need to add all kinds of DOM on the fly. [2] The D3's data binding seems do similar thing as ng-repeat, but I got a problem to access the repeat DOM elements when use ng-repeat. Refer to my post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386858/how-to-add-style-or-attr-to-ng-repeat-element/27387826?noredirect=1#comment43226070_27387826

Comment: @tymeJV I did not use isolate scope, I just accept it from my main controller

Comment: @PSL For "You need to compile the element container removing the directive attribute from the element (If used as an attribute directive)". Could you show me how to do that according to my example? Thanks